# Bootstrap margin resulting in no Changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 on my react pages, and the components of bootstrap seem to be working, but I'm unable to figure out why whenever I add a margin, it is never set. Here is an example piece of code I have in one of my pages:

```
return ( 
    <Fragment> 
        <h1 className="text-center mt-5"> Input Todo</h1>
        
        <form classname="d-flex " onSubmit={
            onSubmitForm
        }> 

            <input type="text" 
                placeholder="add todo" 
                className = "form-control" 
                value={description} 
                onChange = {e => setDescription(e.target.value)}>
            </input>

            <button className="btn btn-success">Add</button>
        </form>
    </Fragment>
)
```

This produces the following result:

[image]

In my index.html file, here are the bootstrap components (css, javascript) that I'm importing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you're using bootstrap 4, but you're importing bootstrap 3.4, which doesn't have the spacing helper class you're trying to use!

You'll want:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
```